# In Vulkan can you have a depth buffer for each colour attachment?

Tags: vulkan

In Vulkan if you want to write to a colour buffer with a depth buffer you create a framebuffer attachment for the colour, and one attachment for the depth buffer. Then when you create the subpass description you make the depth and stencil attachment pointer point to your depth buffer, but it seems there's only one pointer:

```
VkSubpassDescription subpass_description = {};
subpass_description.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpass_description.colorAttachmentCount = vk_attachment_descriptions.size();
subpass_description.pColorAttachments = vk_attachment_references.data();
subpass_description.pDepthStencilAttachment;
```

Although the subpass accepts multiple colour attachments it seems as though there's only one pDepthStencilAttachment pointer. Does Vulkan only allow one depth and stencil buffer when writing to multiple colour attachments?

Comment: There exist things called "early-z kill" and "hierarchical z buffer", which let the hardware kill fragments before their shaders have a chance to exist, saving performance. With this, how do you imagine it working for different color attachments? Unfortunately, you can't simply not write to some attachment too. But you could use a blending hack to make it save value or not by writing 1/0 to alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Vulkan only allow one depth and stencil buffer when writing to multiple colour attachments?

Yes.